# How to restrict user input to a specific intent in dialogflow v2 using the inline editor/fulfilment

Tags: dialogflow-es

Lets say I have two intents "Intent1" and "Intent2" and both intents are triggered by the word/training phrase "yes".

If I go into the dialogflow intents tab and from there enter intent1-context and intent2-context into the respective input contexts is there a way to isolate the Intent I want the word "yes" to trigger? And to do this from within the inline editor?

I'm sending responses back to the user from the inline editor eg:

```
function send_response(agent)
{

    agent.add("Say 'yes' to trigger Intent2");

}
```

But when the user says 'yes' either Intent1 or Intent2 will be triggered because they both take 'yes' as input.

In a previous post I was given some advice re: agent.setContext but implementing this didn't seem to work. Not sure if that was the right method for what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks.

Comment: set output context from your webhook and give the same context in the input of intent

Comment: It sounds like you're doing the correct thing with `setContext()`. Can you update your question to include how you're using the code to do this and screen shots from the two Intents in question to illustrate how you have set the Input Contexts?

Comment: The issue wasn't with setContext. I had entered an action name into the "Enter action name" box under actions and parameters and that was causing grief. If I should delete the question let me know. Thanks for replying tho.

Comment: I did have another ques...some of my intents require the same user input eg. yes and no - so i created a single entity called 'response' to handle the user input for yes and no. And i wanted to set response as a parameter for multiple intents. But even though i'm setting the context it doesn't look like i'm able to sue the same entity for multiple intents. Is that correct? Or can I use the same entity but have to use a different parameter name and value?